# Oracle get first preceding and following rows ordered by time in another table

Tags: oracle, group-by, analytic-functions

I have 2 tables each of which have a timestamp column. How do I query for each row in A, the first preceding and following timestamps in B ?

I want:

A.id A.timestamp first_preceding(B.timestamp) first_following(B.timestamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.timestamp, b0.timestamp, b1.timestamp
FROM a, b b0, b b1
WHERE
b0.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM b WHERE timestamp < a.timestamp)
AND b1.timestamp = (SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM b WHERE timestamp > a.timestamp);
```

Comment: You can get the IDs of the B rows by adding `, b0.id, b1.id` to the list of columns.

Comment: yes but I need the ids of rows in b for which the b.timestamp is a maximum or minimum, not just all ids in the cross product

Comment: I think the WHERE clause picks out the relevant rows for you.  That's why `b0.timestamp, b1.timestamp' should work, and why I expect that the `id` column is available in the same way.  Are you seeing something different?  I suppose that if there are multiple rows in B satisfying (for example) the `b0` test, then since there are multiple `b0.id` values, the `DISTINCT` would give you a separate row for each.  Is that the problem?

Comment: wow I didn't know you could do that. I'm having trouble seeing what's going on here - why can I select b0.id even though b0 is max(timestamp) ?

Comment: `b0` is a row in the table `b` (that's what the `b b0` means), so once you have that row you can get any column you want.  The `WHERE` clause just makes sure that `b0`'s timestamp is as large as you want it.  Also, note that in the subquery, `timestamp` is short for `b.timestamp` since you're selecting from `b`.  Does that help?

Comment: it reads as if b0 and b1 are tables of 1 row each - how can one know that they are rows not tables ?

Comment: I'm not quite following you, but what I just said about `b b0` should make it clear that `b0` is a row.